# Variables declared in shell script not being recognized as a variable and instead a command

Tags: bash, shell, variable-assignment

Here is the script that I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
directory1 = ~/path/to/directory/
directory2 = ~/path/to/directory2/
diff -r $directory1 $directory2 || echo "files are different"
```

And here is the output/error message that appears:

```
./compare.sh: line 2: directory1: command not found
./compare.sh: line 3: directory2: command not found
diff: missing operand after `-r'
diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
files are different
```

I know that there is a problem in a way that I defined directory1 and directory2, but I don't exactly know what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are used as delimiters when assigning variables in bash; you should remove them, otherwise your variables don't exist (i.e. are empty) so the line

```
directory1 = ~/path/to/directory/
```

actually means "call program `directory1` with arguments `=` and `~/path/to/directory`, hence the " command not found".

Similarly, your call to

```
diff -r $directory1 $directory
```

is equivalent to

```
diff -r
```

which is indeed missing parameters.

You might also want to quote path parameters to correctly handle spaces:

```
#!/bin/bash
directory1=~/path/to/directory/
directory2=~/path/to/directory2/
diff -r "$directory1" "$directory2" || echo "files are different"
```